# How to reduce pixelation of render?

Tags: rendering

Very new to blender so maybe it's a simple solution - file attached

Not sure if it's an issue with the texture or render settings
any help much appreciated!

[image: snippet of render]

Comment: Yep - I spose I have to sculpt it more?

Comment: Actually looked it up and applied object > shade smooth and fixed it up! thanks for articulating the problem properly for me!!

Comment: Your welcome. Transferring to answer…

Answer (score 1):

Transferred from comment:

This is because the mesh is not shaded smooth, so the individual faces are reflecting light differently, like a disco ball. Confirm this by going into solid view, and seeing if the square-like divisions are still there.

To fix it, go to Object -> Shade Smooth, and the normals should now be averaged across the faces, making them appear curved as desired.